# Why does the ladder operator contain the $\hbar ω$ part?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

For homework I was deriving the ground state wavefunction for quantum harmonic oscillator using the ladder operator method.

From what I've understood, the whole idea starts by factorizing the hamiltonian operator $H=\frac{1}{2m}(p^2+m^2\omega^2x^2)$ much in the same way we could factorize $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$. That is we want to calculate what does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}(m^2\omega^2x^2-ip)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}(m^2\omega^2+ip)=\frac{1}{2m}(m^2\omega^2x^2-ip)(m^2\omega^2+ip)$ equal to.

However, this is not exactly the case as the ladder operators have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{h\omega}}$ term inside them so we have that $a^†a=\frac{1}{2mh\omega}(m^2\omega^2x^2-ip)(m^2\omega^2+ip)=\frac{1}{h\omega}H+\frac{1}{2}$ and $aa^†=\frac{1}{2mh\omega}(m^2\omega^2x^2+ip)(m^2\omega^2-ip)=\frac{1}{h\omega}H-\frac{1}{2}$.

Using these and the fact that $[a, a^†]=1$ we can prove that if $\psi$ is an energy eigenstate of value $E_n$, then $a\psi$ is too with energy eigenstate with $E_n-h\omega$. Finally using the fact that the energy cannot be negative we can say that $a\psi _0=0$ to get a simple differential equation to solve.

What happens when we define the ladder operators exactly as if they were factorizing the Hamiltonian?

So, for clarity let's define $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}(m^2\omega^2x^2+ip)$. In this case we have that $b^†b=\frac{1}{2m}(m^2\omega^2x^2-ip)(m^2\omega^2+ip)=\frac{1}{2m}(\omega^2m^2x^2+p^2-mh\omega)=H-\frac{1}{2}h\omega\Leftrightarrow H=b^†b+\frac{1}{2}h\omega$

and using largely the same ideas $H=bb^†-\frac{1}{2}h\omega$. Using these we get that $[b, b^†]=bb^†-b^†b=H+\frac{1}{2}h\omega-(H-\frac{1}{2}h\omega)=h\omega$.

Using these relations we can again prove that if $\psi$ is an energy eigenstate of value $E_n$, then $b\psi$ is too with energy eigenstate with $E_n-h\omega$. I can show it here:

$Hb\psi=(bb^†-\frac{1}{2}h\omega)b\psi=b(b^†b-b\frac{1}{2}h\omega)\psi=b(bb^†-\frac{1}{2}h\omega-h\omega)\psi=b(H-h\omega)\psi=(E_n-h\omega)b\psi$.

If my calculations above are correct, you can do the exact same trick using these $b$ operators. So the question is why not define the ladder operators like this? Every time I went to see an explanation for the ladder operator method, nobody could really explain properly what is the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{h\omega}}$-term doing in the ladder operator. Are my calculations here incorrect or does using it simplify something more complicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your product $a^\dagger a = \frac{H}{\hbar\omega} + \frac12$ is dimensionless, because your $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are dimensionless.

If the $
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\ket{\psi_n}
$ are the *normalized* eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with energy $(n+\frac12)\hbar\omega$, successive states are related by

\begin{align}
a\ket{\psi_n} &= \sqrt{n+1}\ket{\psi_{n+1}}
\\
a^\dagger\ket{\psi_n} &= \sqrt n \ket{\psi_{n-1}}
\end{align}

as is shown in most introductory quantum textbooks and in [some online notes](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Ejim/PHYS424_17F/Class%20Notes/Class_5.pdf).

Your suggestion of a dimensionful $b$ simplifies the definition of the ladder operators, but that just moves the complexity elsewhere: $\ket{\psi_n}$ and $b\ket{\psi_{n-1}}$ describe the same state, but now have different units. Repeated applications of the raising operator don’t give you an excited state: they give instead an excited state with some dimensional baggage.

Comment: Oh I see. I calculated the relations you mentioned with the b-operators and got hω-terms multiplying the constants. So the answer is that a-operators are bit more handy to use than the b-operators.

Answer (score 2):

Because $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ is easier to work with than $[b,b^\dagger] = \hbar \omega$ in calculations.